# grunt usemin and IE conditional comments

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Supposedly, I have something like this in my index.html

```
<!-- build:js lib.js -->
<!--[if (!IE)|(gt IE 8)]><!--><script src="lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="lib/jquery/jquery-ie8.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

I'm using useminPrepare/usemin along with concat and uglify, to combine all javascript files into one, uglify them and then replace the reference in resulting html, pointing to just this one file. This works fine if you can narrow it down to single blocks. But what with the situation above? Obviously, I don't want it to pack both versions of jquery into one file. I would like it to split into two paths, creating two versions of lib.js - one combining all common files plus files from within certain IFs, the other - all common files plus files from the other IF.

Is something like this possible? AFAIK, usemin is really plain and all it can do is just parse single blocks. You cannot close one block and then open it again (it will complain). You cannot open one block and continue it later. What are your solutions for this, supposedly frequent, problem?

I suppose I could split it into more separate blocks, but then the point of minification and concatenation onto one file is sort of moot. Ideally, I would like it to traverse certain path through html, gather all files and build them into one file, then traverse, go another path and build another file (i.e. one for ie8 and the other for rest). Any thoughts here?